# when i write this i see no errors but it opens a jpg file instead of a mp3 file

Tags: python

```
music_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Sannidhay\\Music'
songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
print(songs)
os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))
```

Comment: Probably there is a jpg file in the directory, like an album cover.

Comment: What is the output of `print(songs)`?

Answer (score 0):

You must try printing the file name for `songs[0]`. It is probably a `jpg` file and thus it is being opened by your program. Remove all non mp3 files from the `Music` directory and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

@Sannidhay Try to set a default program to open a music file in Music App or Windows media player and after that run your script.